# Question on center-stable manifold

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Assume that you have a gradient system smooth enough and a fixed point $x_{0}$. Is it true that if $x_{0} \in \omega(x)$ then $\gamma^{+}(x)$ must intersect the local center-stable manifold of $x_{0}$? Thanks

Comment: You should explain your notation: what do $\omega(x)$ and $\gamma^+(x)$ mean?

Comment: I think $\gamma^+(x)$ is the forward orbit through $x$ and $\omega(x)$ is the $\omega$-limit set of that orbit.